# Add audio in dialog (Bixby)

Tags: bixby

This is my first question, new and fresh, hello guys.

As the title mentions, is there any workaround or way to add audio inside dialog-speech-template? As it doesn't support mp3, and only wav, I found it hard to implement.

The audio I wanted to get is origin from API, and hence it's not possible for me to download the mp3 file and convert it (as changes may happen to the audio).

Is there any programmatic way to convert the mp3 audio to wav? I am pretty new to Bixby, hope elders here can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Bixby SSML only for certain wav format. Please refer [SSML#AudioClip](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/ref-topics/ssml#audio-clips) for details. There are also instructions how to convert using ffmpeg tool.

To support mp3 format, you can raise a [Feature Request](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/360000183273-Feature-Requests) in our community. This forum is open to other Bixby developers who can upvote it, leading to more visibility within the community and with the Product Management team.

Comment: Is there any clearer instruction on how to convert using ffmpeg tool? I am trying to convert inside the code, not by download and convert manually,is it possible?

and thanks for your response :D

Comment: You need to convert it before using as a resource. There is no way convert it in Bixby.